# Do I need wide or regular width snowboarding boots?

Tags: footwear, snowboarding

I'm in the process of buying new snowboarding boots and considering buying Burton Photon BOA, but they have regular and wider versions of this boot.

I could not find any way to determine if I need a wide or regular fit, so my question is, how do I know?

The boot size that fits (according to Mondo in the Burton size chart) is 10.5US (Mondo 285), but which one should I go with, wide or regular?

My foot width is exactly 11 cm (measured using the method described [here](https://www.kohls.com/feature/shoesizeguide.jsp#adultSizing)).

Comment: Can you try them out?

Comment: @Willeke Nope, unfortunately, it is not an option in my situation

Comment: you should really not buy shoes without trying them

Answer (score 0):

I found this image[image: foot mondo point to width ratio] on the internet that provides a relation of your Mondo to foot width. The way width should be measured is explained in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkSJJ6_1KYc&t=181s, also check out https://snowboardbootsizer.com for more instructions on how to measure your foot for snowboard boots.

Comment: What is the source of the image you provided?

Comment: Can you explain how this answered your question as to which sized Burton boot (regular/wide) fits your foot better?